# How to display current time + time interval in a PowerPoint slide?

Tags: text, dynamic, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I have a Microsoft PowerPoint document and I have a slide which I display during a short break. I would like the slide to show the time when the slide was shown + a time interval. This is to show when the audience should be back again.

So simply a text container with (pseudo code):

```
text = time.now() + interval(5 minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in a more powerpointy way, by making multiple slides that say, for example, "presentation begins again in 5 minutes", next slide "...4 mintues", next slide "...3 minutes" etc. Then put an auto timer on each slide to auto advance after 1 minute.

Comment: I was going for a simple static text displaying the time when the slide was shown + and interval. So it wouldn't count down, just show at what time the audience should be back.